# Adding Hidden Text to Submit Form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

So I've got this login form, and what I'm trying to do is append an additional piece of data, for example let's say it's -123, to their username behind the scenes as this will determine which site they log into.

I've got the below in my HTML page, but unfortunately this is not working. Any ideas?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('submit').click(function () {
 $('input[username="username[]"]').map(function () {
  $(this).val($(this).attr('username') + '-123' + $(this).val());
   alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```
<form method="post" action="http://fake.com/example/Login,loginForm.sdirect" id="loginForm">
<input type="hidden" name="formids" value="loginButton,username,password,Hidden" />
<input type="hidden" name="seedids" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitmode" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitname" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="Hidden" id="Hidden" value="X" />
    <div class="login-fields" style="text-align:left; margin-left:0px; margin-top:16px; height:217px; width:225px; background-image:url(images/please_login.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
     <div style="position:relative; left:24px; top:48px;">username:<br /><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" size="20" /></div>
 <div style="position:relative; left:24px; top:60px;">password:<br /><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" size="20" /></div>
 <div style="position:relative; left:124px; top:72px;"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have no `<input username="username[]">` element in your HTML. Did you mean `[name=username]`?

Answer (score 1):

The logic you had for setting the `val()` using `map()` was very convoluted and not at all what you need. Instead, after selecting the `#username` element, you can pass a function to `val()` which appends the required string to the current value, like this:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // this is only for the sake of this example, remove if not needed

  $('#username').val(function(i, v) {
    return v + '-123';
  });
});
```

```css
.login-fields {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  height: 217px;
  width: 225px;
  background-image: url(images/please_login.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.login-fields>div:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  left: 24px;
  top: 48px;
}

.login-fields>div:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  left: 24px;
  top: 60px;
}

.login-fields>div:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  left: 124px;
  top: 72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="http://fake.com/example/Login,loginForm.sdirect" id="loginForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="formids" value="loginButton,username,password,Hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" name="seedids" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="submitmode" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="submitname" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Hidden" id="Hidden" value="X" />

  <div class="login-fields">
    <div>
      username:<br />
      <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" size="20" />
    </div>
    <div>
      password:<br />
      <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" size="20" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that you shouldn't use inline `style` attributes. Place styling in an external stylesheet instead - as I did in the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the elements by ID, as they all have ID's, then change the value before submitting the form using `val()`. The `submit` event fires before the form is submitted.

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit', function() {
    $('#username').val(function(v) {
        return v + '-123';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change script like below. you can able to attach name behind 123 and also `$(this).attr('name')` gives value of attribute as name. At connection time with api service call remove this `event.preventDefault();`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
         $('#username').map(function () {
          $(this).val($(this).attr('name') + '-123' + $(this).val());
           alert($(this).val());
          });
        });
  </script>
```

output in alert box:

```
username-123<value in input tag>
```

username from below tag

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" size="20" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script like below

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type="submit"]').on("click", function (e) {
                $('#username').val(function (index, value) {
                    return value + '-123';
                })
                alert($('#username').val());
            });
        });

    </script >
```

Comment: That has worked an absolute treat mate! I might need to change it up slightly so that the hidden text goes before the username, but I'm hoping it'll be a case of just changing it to '-rfq' + return value; instead.